# Mixed content error, resolve by restarting puma

Tags: ruby, puma

I am running a website using puma and ruby.

HTTPS is configured in nginx.

Occasionally, we encounter error as seen in the following picture. And, strangely, it is resolved by restarting puma. Simply running `sudo systemctl restart puma` will clear this up.

[image: Error on website]

What is wrong with my setup?

Why does it serve the contents in http? And why is it solved only by restarting puma?

This error starts randomly. Last week we don't have it at all, but this week already four times.

Any help to guide me solve this permanently is appreciated.

Thank you.

---

Edits to answer the comments:

The following is the code that generates the stylesheet links:

```
<%# stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', protocol: :relative %>
<%# javascript_include_tag 'application', protocol: :relative %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', controller_name, media: 'all', protocol: :relative %>
<% if session[:responsive].nil? || session[:responsive] == 1 %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "#{controller_name}_responsive", media: 'all', protocol: :relative %>
<% end %>
```

Viewing source while error occurred shows that it has `http://` in in front of the css URL. After restarting puma, it is only `//` without `http:` like this:

[image: correct one]

Comment: How are the stylesheets loaded in the header?

Comment: Additionally the nginx config could be helpful.

Comment: I'd debug into the code where the `<link rel="stylesheet"` is being rendered. It seems to not be issue with puma, it looks like the HTML you render starts to request HTTP stylesheet. Restartingh Puma probably resets your app state, and fixes the issue temporarily, until it's state get's messed up again...

Comment: @DennyMueller I put the code below my question. Anything I should revise? Thanks.

Comment: Thats an odd thing. So the url shows something like `//www.foo.bar/style.css`?
do you by any chance have `config.action_controller.asset_host` set in your enviroment config (e.g. production.rb)?

Comment: In production.rb there is a line: config.action_controller.asset_host = ENV['ASSET_HOST']

And using env:

ASSET_HOST=//thedomain.com